# Is it okay to include methods in a view model or should they be placed in another part of the code?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin Forms ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class CFSPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    #region Constructor

    public CFSPageViewModel()
    {
        PTBtnCmd = new Command<string>(PTBtn);
        OnTappedCmd = new Command<string>(OnTapped);
    }

    #endregion

    # region Commands

    public ICommand PTBtnCmd { get; set; }
    public ICommand OnTappedCmd { get; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void OnTapped(string btnText)
    {
        Utils.SetState(btnText, CFS, SET.Cfs);
        CFSMessage = Settings.cfs.TextLongDescription();
    }

    private void PTBtn(string btnText)
    {
        Utils.SetState(btnText, PT);
        SetLangVisible(btnText);
        SetLangSelected(btnText);
        CFSMessage = Settings.cfs.TextLongDescription();
    }


}
```

I was previously sending a message with MessageCenter to my C# back end code but now have removed MessageCenter so the methods are part of the ViewModel.

Is this a safe thing to do? I heard that MessageCenter messages passing around between ViewModels for everything was not the best of solutions.

Note that here is the way I had been doing it before:

MyPageViewModel.cs

```
PTBtnCmd = new Command<Templates.WideButton>((btn) =>             
              MessagingCenter.Send<CFSPageViewModel, Templates.WideButton>(
              this, "PTBtn", btn));
```

MyPage.xaml.cs

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CFSPageViewModel, Templates.WideButton>(
        this, "PTBtn", (s, btn) =>
        {
            Utils.SetState(btn.Text, vm.PT);
            SetLangVisible(btn.Text);
            SetLangSelected(btn.Text);
            vm.CFSMessage = Settings.cfs.TextLongDescription();
        });
```

Note that methods such as SetLangVisible were also in MyPage.xaml.cs

Comment: In `MyPage.xaml.cs` where was the `Utils.SetState(btn.Text, vm.PT)`, `SetLangVisible(btn.Text)`, `SetLangSelected(btn.Text)` etc methods? Where they inside `MyPage.xaml.cs`?

Comment: Common practice to Bind to commands from view model.

Comment: @lolelo - yes they were.  But in the new idea they are in the ViewModel's code.

Comment: @Nkosi - Can you give an example of what you mean using my code.

Comment: @Nkosi If the methods are view related -  put them in `MyPage.xaml.cs`. If you  need the methods to be globally accessible throughout your application (from other views etc) and want to be able to unit test them - put them in the view model.

Comment: @lolelo - the methods are in response to clicking of buttons that came from the view model.  But if they are put in the MyPage.xaml.cs what would be a good way to initiate those methods from the view other than using the messaging from ViewModel to MyPage.xaml.cs?

Comment: @Alan2 Use a event handler

Comment: @lolelo - Can you give an example of how you would do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add an event handler to your `Button`simply:

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="MyProject.Views.MyPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button Text="PTBtn" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

In code behind:

```
namespace MyProject.Views
{
    public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MyPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        void Handle_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            ((Button)sender).BackgroundColor = Color.Blue; // sender is the control the event occured on

            // Here call your methods depending on what they do/if they are view related
            /*
            Utils.SetState(btn.Text, vm.PT);
            SetLangVisible(btn.Text);
            SetLangSelected(btn.Text);
            vm.CFSMessage = Settings.cfs.TextLongDescription();
            */
        }
    }
}
```

All the events that can have a event handler assigned to it is listed in yellow with E:
[image]

---

The `Command` fires first and you can add `CanExecute` as a second parameter in the constructor - which will also stop both the command and the event handler from being executed.

I would also rename the `Command` to something like `SelectLanguageCommand` - to distinguish it from a ui action. That way you can disconnect the button from the command and connect the command to other ui - if you decide you want to change the view in the future. It would also be easier to understand when unit testing.

---

> Is this a safe thing to do? I heard that MessageCenter messages passing around between ViewModels for everything was not the best of solutions.

You could register all your view models with `DependencyService`

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DependencyService.Register<AboutViewModel>();
    DependencyService.Register<CFSPageViewModel>();
    DependencyService.Register<MyPageViewModel>();
    MainPage = new AppShell();
}
```

Set `BindingContext` of the views to the instances registered:

```
public AboutPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = DependencyService.Get<AboutViewModel>();
}
```

And get the ViewModel instance anywhere you need it. That way you don't have to deal with subscriptions as you need to when using `MessagingCenter`.

Wether it is safe or not - I am not sure.